# Wallpaper in dual-monitors with different resolution

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, resolution, desktop-customization

OS: WinXP

I got 2 monitors with main one in 1280x1024 and the secondary in 1600x1200. When setting wallpaper in best fit, it will fit my main screen but leave a lot padding area in secondary. Since the wallpaper is in same resolution. Is there anyway to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a program called [display fusion](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/) that lets you do multi monitor wallpapers.  I think it also lets you specify separate wallpaper settings for each monitor.  I have been using it for a while and it works pretty well.

Comment: I am using wallpaper master to periodically changing wallpaper. Is there a way to use both application? Thanks.

Comment: Among others the feature list of display fusion reads "Randomly change your desktop wallpaper using local images or images from Flickr"

Comment: @Martin: Display Fusion does all you want, including wallpaper rotation.

Comment: @akira: yes, that's what I understood, I wanted to point Stan to that.

Comment: sorry, wrong @ word, i meant @stan, not you.