# Is there any way to fit wallpaper to larger monitor (has multiple monitors) resolution?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, resolution, desktop-customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wallpaper in dual-monitors with different resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/155198/wallpaper-in-dual-monitors-with-different-resolution)

I got 2 monitors with main one in 1280x1024 and the secondary in 1600x1200. Setting wallpaper by regular image viewer program will make wallpaper size fit to "main" monitor. Is there any way to make the wallpaper fit to larger monitor (secondary in my case) without switch larger monitor to primary monitor? Thanks.

Comment: It's not same question. One is asking for a tool to make wallpaper fit to both monitors. This question is asking for how to make wallpaper fit to larger monitor by any image viewer or even windows!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/dual-monitors-use-a-different-wallpaper-on-each-desktop/) has an article about using a different wallpaper on each desktop on dual monitors. With this method, I think you can set the same wallpaper with different resolutions on each monitor.

Comment: Perfect for XP. How to do this for Windows 7?